# if else combined with calculations

Tags: python, if-statement, equation

I'm writing a BMI calculator program, with options for both metric and imperial. My problem is when I try it for metric, the program must be running the numbers through the imperial equation, because I am getting a crazy answer.
Here is my code:

```
var1 = "imperial"

print "Do you use imperial or metric?"
ans = raw_input()
var1 = ans
if var1:
    print "What is your weight?"
    weighti = float(raw_input()) 
    print "What is your height?"
    heighti = float(raw_input())
    print "Your body mass index, BMI, is", weighti * 703 / heighti**2
else:
    print "What is your weight?"
    weightm = float(raw_input())
    print "What is your height?"
    heightm = float(raw_input())
    print "your body mass index, BMI, is", weightm / heightm**2
```

Comment: Do you understand what `if` does?

Comment: You should drop the `var1 = ans`, and use `if ans == var1:` as if statement

Comment: I see misunderstanding here, in statement  `if var1:`you check whether var1 exists, not its current value.

Comment: Note that any text value evaluates to True, so any answer other than an empty response (i.e. "") would result in the first block being executed and the second being ignored.

Answer (score 2):

You're not using the `if` statement correctly.

`if var1:` would only work if `var1` is already a bool, but it's a string (either "imperial" or "metric").

Try the following:

```
var1 = "imperial"

print "Do you use imperial or metric?"
ans = raw_input()
var1 = ans
if var1 == 'imperial':
    print "What is your weight?"
    weighti = float(raw_input()) 
    print "What is your height?"
    heighti = float(raw_input())
    print "Your body mass index, BMI, is", weighti * 703 / heighti**2
else:
    print "What is your weight?"
    weightm = float(raw_input())
    print "What is your height?"
    heightm = float(raw_input())
    print "your body mass index, BMI, is", weightm / heightm**2
```

Additionally, there's a few things that need improvement on your code.

The first one is that you should use more descriptive variable names. `var1` tells me nothing about the variable's content. `ans` is a bit better.

The second one is that you're defining `var1` as "imperial" in the beginning, but you don't use `var1` before reassigning it to something else. It's redundant and it would work without the `var1 = "imperial"` line.

The third one is that the `var1` variable itself is also redundant. If you're doing `var1 = ans` then why not use `ans` itself?

The fourth is that if the answer isn't either "imperial" or "metric", it will always default to metric. You could check that and let the user know that his entry is invalid if it's not either of the valid values.

So a better version would be:

```
print "Do you use imperial or metric?"
ans = raw_input()
if ans == 'imperial':
    print "What is your weight?"
    weighti = float(raw_input()) 
    print "What is your height?"
    heighti = float(raw_input())
    print "Your body mass index, BMI, is", weighti * 703 / heighti**2
elif ans == 'metric':
    print "What is your weight?"
    weightm = float(raw_input())
    print "What is your height?"
    heightm = float(raw_input())
    print "your body mass index, BMI, is", weightm / heightm**2.
else:
    print 'Sorry, but that input is not valid. Please enter either "imperial" or "metric".'
```

Comment: So simple question but in your code not all accidents are considered. I would write `elif var == "metric":` instead `else:`. These details are important for begginers but it is my own opinion.

Comment: @dannyxn right, added that in a better version that points out some other things that could also be done better. It's still not the most efficient, but it should give a beginner some tips without completely changing his code.